# Why is my image not loading correctly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've stored `B1.png` named image in `Images.xcassets` folder.

Here's my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let width:CGFloat = 320;
        let height:CGFloat  = 568;
        var buttonTitles = ["Click to begin"]
        var view:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,width,height))
        self.view.addSubview(view);
        var backgroundImage:UIImage = UIImage(named:"B1")
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: view.frame)
        imageView.image = backgroundImage
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

> **Problem:** when I run the project it builds with no errors but only displays a white screen in the simulator.

Comment: OK, here's a tip: Clean up your language.

Comment: Hey if you decide to down vote would you pretty please leave me at least a one sentence comment on why :D???

Comment: You need to refine the problem. Either in the debugger or with println statements determine where the problem is. start with did the image load? `println("backgroundImage: \(backgroundImage)")` You need to provide as much relevant information as possible, just tossing up some code and asking is not enough to get any meaningful help, probably the reason for the down votes. Show some work on your part trying to resolve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I find the "drive-by" down-votes without a reason to be non-helpful, SO is not all that friendly sometimes. But we do get fed-up with all the posts that have shown no work on the OP's part.

Answer (score 0):

Value of optional type UIImage is not unwrapped, try this (note the !)

```
        var backgroundImage:UIImage = UIImage(named:"B1")!
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the image in your project folder not in Images.xcassets and use:

```
var backgroundImage:UIImage = UIImage(named:"B1.png") // with file type
```